# How to crawl book details of 1000 books simultaneously from goodreads.com using its API?

Tags: java, xml, api, dom, web-crawler

I'm parsing `XML` files and adding a new field named `<description>` to each file with value crawled from the GoodReads.com website using its `API`. The code successfully crawls book details (when `ISBN` matches at `GoodReads.com`). Using the developer key (provided by `GoodReads.com`) I am allowed to crawl `1000` books a day but the service does not allow me to download these at one time. Normally, after crawling 20 or more books, it stops allowing to access books by returning `404` or `403` `status`. Please help!

I have already contacted GoodReads.com developer team to allow me more than `1000` books for the dataset I am using in my research experiments but they haven't responded yet. But here, the problem is, even I cannot crawl `1000` books simultaneously.

Here is the code I am using to crawl books (by calling from the main program):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class GoodReadsCrawler {



private static final String API_KEY = "some key";
private static final String ISBN_TO_ID_URL = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn_to_id?key=" + API_KEY;
private static final String BOOK_DETAILS_URL = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO: Change "1856058387" to any valid ISBN 1933705000
    // String bookId = isbnToId("1856058387");

    // String bookId = isbnToId("1933705000");
    // print("Book Id: " + bookId);
    // String bookData = getBookDescription(bookId);
    // print("Description tag: " + bookData);

}

private static void print(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}

// private static String isbnToId(String isbn) {
public static String isbnToId(String isbn) {
    try {
        print("Getting id of " + isbn);
        String requestUrl = ISBN_TO_ID_URL + "&isbn=" + isbn;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(requestUrl);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        return result.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}

// private static String getBookDescription(String bookId) {
public static String getBookDescription(String bookId) {
    try {
        print("Getting book data...");
        String bookUrl = BOOK_DETAILS_URL + bookId;
        Document documment = Jsoup.connect(bookUrl).get();
        Element descriptionTag = documment.getElementById("description");
        return descriptionTag.getElementsByTag("span").last().text();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Read the [terms of use](https://www.goodreads.com/api/terms), item 1.

Comment: @Andy Turner This means, we need to introduce 'delay' of at least 'one second' after each book 'description' is accessed?

Comment: yes. There isn't much point in trying to do it in parallel either.